# How can I remove the reflection effect in JFreeChart?

Tags: java, charts, histogram, jfreechart

I am drawing a histogram in JFreeChart. The columns of the histogram are colored red. But each column also has a white stripe on its left side. This stripe looks like a reflection effect. How can I remove the reflection effect to get solid colored bars instead? For more information, please see the attached screenshot.

[image: Histogram with Reflection Effect]

Comment: Try `StandardBarPainter`, examined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7076305/230513). If this is not a duplicate, please [edit] your question to include a [mre] that shows your revised approach.

Comment: More examples are pictured [here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A230513+setBarPainter).

Comment: @trashgod Yes, that worked! That question refers to a CategoryPlot, and my question refers to an XYPlot. But in both answers, we use the setBarPainter method. I also found a related question that you answered: "How to change JFreeChart vertical bar to a solid color?" https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71025895/how-to-change-jfreechart-vertical-bar-to-a-solid-color/71027246

Comment: @trashgod I disagree with one of the three questions marked as duplicates: "JFreeChart MouseListener doesn't resolve chart elements." That question relates to listening for mouse events, and this question relates to drawing a reflection effect. I agree with the other two duplicate questions. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7999587/jfreechart-mouselistener-doesnt-resolve-chart-elements

Comment: Your point is well taken, but the illustration, like yours, may guide future users. If you disagree, please don't hesitate to flag for moderator attention or post on [MetaSO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=tangential+duplicates). As you had some trouble locating the answer, I'd welcome additions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code sets the bar painter for the histogram to the StandardXYBarPainter which does not draw a reflection effect. For more information, please see the related questions [JFreeChart BarChart -> NO gradient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7076305/jfreechart-barchart-no-gradient) and [How to change JFreeChart vertical bar to a solid color?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71025895/how-to-change-jfreechart-vertical-bar-to-a-solid-color/71027246) When I searched for my question, I did not see those questions because I searched for the word 'reflection' instead of 'gradient'. @trashgod referred me to these questions in his comment.

```
((XYBarRenderer) ((XYPlot) histogram.getPlot()).getRenderer()).setBarPainter(new StandardXYBarPainter());
```